# Regarding the degree of a map $f:S^n\rightarrow S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

The degree of a map $f:S^n\rightarrow S^n$ is defined as an integer d such that $f_*(\alpha) = d\alpha$ where $\alpha$ generates the infinite cyclic group $H_n(S^n)$.
So my question is, in some cases the map $f$ will defined from $S^n$ to a copy of $S^n$. So for degree to be well defined we need a canonical mapping from $S^n$ to all its copies. Now this is essentially what one might call as the identity map. Can someone tell me how this map is defined?

Comment: Any orientation preserving difeomorphism induces the identity on homology

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez whether a function is orientation preserving or reversing depends on the choice of generators I take for $S_1^n$ and $S_2^n$. And what i want is essentially a canonical map that defines this generator for every copy so that the degree is well defined. I am a little rusty with this so bear with me.

Comment: Degree is defined for any map between connected, compact, oriented manifolds. They don't need to be $S^n$. If you want to identify a manifold homeomorphic to $S^n$ with $S^n$ and get the same degree, you have to do that identification by an orientation-preserving homeomorphism.

Comment: @Thorgott I understand what you are saying but my knowledge of orientation is limited to what is defined by Homology. So given a map f between manifolds M and N, it can be orientation preserving or reversing depending on the choice of orientations on M and N or in other words the choice of generators for $H_n(M)$ and $H_n(N)$

Comment: But for my degree to be well defined I need a canonical generator defined for all copies of $S^n$

Comment: It simply doesn't make sense to talk about the integer degree of a map from $S^n$ to an abstract copy of $S^n$ if you have not specified an orientation on that abstract copy.

Comment: I should specify that this is because there do exist orientation-reversing automorphisms of $S^n$. If you had a manifold like $\mathbb{CP}^{2n}$, which doesn't possess an orientation-reversing automorphism, then a choice of orientation of $\mathbb{CP}^{2n}$ would also specify a choice of orientation on each abstract copy of it.